# What does 'var vm = this;' mean in angular controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I was browsing some stuff on github and I saw inside controller.js, someone had put the following:

```
function ImageController ($scope, $timeout) {
   var vm = this;
}
```

What is this used for?

Comment: it just a scope closure  for `this`, but `this` is link to controller. your `ImageController` instantiated with `new ImageControllers(/*$injections*/)`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `vm` in this case means `viewmodel`.

It is a shortcut, so instead of writing `this.someMethod()` you can use `vm.someMethod()`.

Very common when you use `Controller As` syntax, so you don´t use the `$scope` by "accident".

Also, the `this` keyword can be messy to use, since it may reference different things depending on where it is used.

Answer (score 6):

> Why?: Helps avoid the temptation of using $scope methods inside a
>   controller when it may otherwise be better to avoid them or move the
>   method to a factory, and reference them from the controller.

you can check full [John Papa Angular Style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controlleras-controller-syntax) to learn deeper...